# FastRefresh in Expo working in vi/gedit/VSCode but not in Vim/Neovim

Tags: file-operations

I am working on an React Native Expo SDK49 project in Arch Linux.

Fast Refresh (changes reflected in Expo Go/emulator when saving changes in file) is working in vi/gedit/VSCode but not in Vim and Neovim.

How to make it work?

Comment: please explain what you expect *fastrefresh* to be done in the context of using Vi like editor

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is yet another case of file system watchers being tripped up by Vim's default way of writing files. The usual workaround is to add the following line to your `vimrc`:

```
set backupcopy=yes
```

From `:help 'backupcopy'`:

```
Making a copy and overwriting the original file:
- Takes extra time to copy the file.
+ When the file has special attributes, is a (hard/symbolic) link or
  has a resource fork, all this is preserved.
- When the file is a link the backup will have the name of the link,
  not of the real file.
```

See also `:help backuptable`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It works perfectly fine now.

Comment: @Mridul if this answer solves your problem, consider accepting it using the v-shaped button to its top left. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `'autoread'` option then Vim will automatically reload the files that are changed:

```
:set autoread
```

More information with [:help 'autoread'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27autoread%27)